# Cannot import tensorflow 1.0.1 after compiled from source

Tags: python, tensorflow, compilation, open-source, bazel

I successfully built tensorflow 1.0.1 from source using optimization flags with the command bazel build -c opt --copt=-mmmx --copt=-msse --copt=-msse2 -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package. After that, I activated my virtualenv and issued a pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl to install in the virtual env this compiled from source version. When I try to import tensorflow in the python code, I receive a error (showing it with -v flag from python interpreter activated):

`#/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.pyc matches #/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.py
import numpy.ma.extras # precompiled from /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.pyc
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pyc matches /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py
import tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow # precompiled from /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pyc
dlopen("/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf_exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so", 102);
Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

I already tried all the possible combinations: With optimization flags, without optimization, etc. None of them works.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 with Bazel versin 0.5.3 and python 2.7. I am not trying to compile anything related with GPU support in tensorflow. Only CPU.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux ubuntu-xenial 4.4.0-91-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:56:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I had some progress here. I tried all the stpes above in a VirtualBox ubuntu machine. It seems that VirtualBox is not fully activating all of these CPU instructions, so in runtime (import tensorflow) I got this error. Do you know how to fully activate it in VirtualBox?